# Code performance optimization : speeding up population of an array in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, vectorization, computation

Part of a longer algorithm, populating the column array `b` takes 80% of the total run time.  The line (see code below) where S1 is calculated in the `for` loop is the bottleneck because it's called an enormously large amount of times due to the nested loops. ***I have tried vectorizing the loops and/or using the `sum` built-in function*** but I always end up with an even higher computation time.

For the sake of simplicity we can look at one single iteration, namely `n = 1` and `n + 1 = 2`. So the 3D array containing the quantity R at each iteration has only two elements : `R(:,:,1)` and `R(:,:,2)`.

[image]

**Where:**

[image]

I have posted here a minimum working sample that you can yourself run:

```
tic

Nz = 3636 ;  % Number of rows 
Nx = 910 ;   % Number of columns

R = rand(Nz, Nx, 2) ;
alpha = 3 ;

  for ii = Nx - 1 : -1 : 2                
     b = zeros(Nz, 1) ;

     for jj = 2 : Nz - 1 
        S  = 0 ;
        S1 = 0 ;
          
         for mm = Nx - 1 : -1 : ii  % Summation 
             S1 = S1 + R(2, mm, 2) + R(2, mm, 1) - (R(1, mm, 2) + R(1, mm, 1)) ; 
             S  = S + (R(jj + 1, mm, 2) + R(jj + 1, mm, 1)) - 2 * (R(jj, mm, 2) + R(jj, mm, 1)) + (R(jj - 1 , mm, 2) + R(jj - 1, mm, 1)) ; 
              
         end

        b(1)  =  2 *(R(1, ii, 1) + 2 * alpha * S1) ;       
        b(jj) =  2 *(R(jj, ii, 1) + alpha * S) ;
     end
 end
toc
```

The current elapsed time is about 28-30 [s] on my laptop (i7-9850H, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB RAM).

I am aware that `b` is reset to zero at each `ii` iteration, but to reduce the sample to bare minimum I omitted a line just before the last `end`: `q = D\b`. It's a linear system solved column by column starting from the right-most column of the grid (most external loop). That's why at every `ii` (column) iteration I compute a new `b` and thus a new solution `q`.

How can I speed up this computation?

**EDIT:**

I tried to vectorize the sum, by eliminating the inner `for` loop and using the function `sum`, but the time increases dramatically.

```
tic

Nz = 3636 ;  % Number of rows 
Nx = 910 ;   % Number of columns

R = rand(Nz, Nx, 2) ;
alpha = 3 ;

  for ii = Nx - 1 : -1 : 2                
     b = zeros(Nz, 1) ;

     for jj = 2 : Nz - 1 
       
         S1 = sum([R(2, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 2), R(2, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 1), - R(1, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 2), R(1,Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 1)]) ; 
         S  = sum([R(jj + 1, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 2), R(jj + 1, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 1), - 2 * R(jj, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 2), 2 * R(jj, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 1), R(jj - 1 , Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 2), R(jj - 1, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 1)]) ; 
              
        b(1)  =  2 *(R(1, ii, 1) + 2 * alpha * S1) ;       
        b(jj) =  2 *(R(jj, ii, 1) + alpha * S) ;
     end
 end
toc
```

Comment: I would store `[2*S1; S]` in a vector and in each `ii` iteration just add the last term to it. The `jj`-loop can also be replaced by some simple block-additions.

Comment: I am mostly worried about all this because you throw away the result each iteration, there is only 1 `b` in the end. Is this really your final code? Beacause it does the same if you just start with `ii=2`. On top of that your optimized code does not give the same result as the original...

Answer (score 4):

Most of the computations are repeated summations that can be converted to `cumsum`. The result `b` is a matrix that you simply can use `D\b` to compute `q` for all columns at once.

```
R = R(:, 2:end-1, :);
sm = sum(R, 3);
S1 = cumsum(sm(2, :) - sm(1, :), 2, 'reverse')
S = cumsum(conv2(sm, [1;-2;1], 'valid'), 2, 'reverse')
b = [2 .* (R(1, :, 1) + 2 * alpha * S1);
     2 .* (R(2:end-1, :, 1) + alpha * S);
     zeros(1, size(R, 2))];
q = D\b;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm just working with your optimized code. Mostly because your optimized code does not do the same as the non optimized one, there are more things that make no sense (`b` is replaced in all of the `ii` loops, so `ii` is superfluous). I give you thus some tips to improve code in general, but I can't fix a broken question.

Tips:

1. make sure your code is easy to read by you.
   `R(2, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 2), R(2, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 1)` is just `R(2, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, 2:1)`, and in fact as you are adding them `R(2, Nx - 1 : -1 : ii, :)`.
2. Indexing an array is much faster if you do it as expected, i.e., in order. You are adding array elements, but reading them in reverse. Just read them normally, i.e. `Nx-1:-1:ii` is just `ii:Nx-1`. Bonus that it's much more readable. In fact the above line is now suddenly `R(2, ii:Nx-1, :)`. Much more readable.
3. Don't create temporary arrays if can be avoided. Particularly if in the end, these will be the size of `R`! You are just indexing it, and you don't care about the ordering because you will add it together.  `S` can be just:

   ```
   S  = sum(R(jj-1:jj+1, ii : Nx-1, :).*cat(3,[1;2;1],[1; -2; 1]),'all') ; 

   % R(jj-1:jj+1, ii : Nx-1, :)   % grabs the needed values
   % cat(3,[1;2;1],[1; -2; 1])    % small trick to multiply the arrays (implicit broadcast)
   % sum(  ,'all')                % add them regardless of shape.
   ```

This already speeds up the code by a lot.

4- Don't overcompute. `S1` does not depend in `jj`, in fact, it's the same for each `ii`. So why compute it `jj` times for each `ii` ?

So, you can change your optimized code to the following for a x1.7 speedup:

```
tic


Nz = 1000 ;  % Number of rows
Nx = 200 ;   % Number of columns


R = rand(Nz, Nx, 2) ;
alpha = 3 ;

for ii = Nx - 1 : -1 : 2
    b1 = zeros(Nz, 1) ;
    
    % we can optimize this one too, but I don't think its the main culprit
    % here. 
    S1 = sum([R(2, ii : Nx-1, 2), R(2, ii : Nx-1, 1),...
            - R(1, ii : Nx-1, 2), R(1,ii : Nx-1, 1)]) ;
        
    b1(1)  =  2 *(R(1, ii, 1) + 2 * alpha * S1) ;
    
    for jj = 2 : Nz - 1
        
        S  = sum(R(jj-1:jj+1, ii : Nx-1, :).*cat(3,[1;2;1],[1; -2; 1]),'all') ;
        b1(jj) =  2 *(R(jj, ii, 1) + alpha * S) ;
    end
end
toc
```

Answer (score 3):

On my laptop (MATLAB R2020a, i7-5500U, 2.4 GHz, 8 GB RAM), your original code runs in about 45 s.

```
Elapsed time is 45.239229 seconds.
```

Your attempt using sum runs in about 191 s.

```
Elapsed time is 191.424418 seconds.
```

@Ander Biguri suggestion runs in about 174 s, which is faster, but not as fast as using `for` loops.

```
Elapsed time is 174.288989 seconds.
```

It appears that MATLAB built-in `sum` function runs slower than the `for` loop, as briefly discussed [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/450854-why-is-manually-adding-elements-of-a-vector-faster-than-passing-a-vector-range-to-sum). The array initialization `b=zeros(Nz,1)` is fast in newer versions of MATLAB (at least since R2019a), but you can [initialize it](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/58055-faster-way-to-initilize-arrays-via-empty-matrix-multiplication) differently if you are using an older version.

@Ander suggestions, however, are noteworthy and we can follow his suggestions, but use `for` loop for the summations:

```
tic

Nz = 3636 ;  % Number of rows 
Nx = 910 ;   % Number of columns

R = rand(Nz, Nx, 2) ;
alpha = 3 ;

for ii = Nx - 1 : -1 : 2                
    b = zeros(Nz, 1) ;
    S1 = 0 ;
    for mm = Nx - 1 : -1 : ii  % Summation 
        S  = S + (R(jj + 1, mm, 2) + R(jj + 1, mm, 1)) - 2 * (R(jj, mm, 2) + R(jj, mm, 1)) + (R(jj - 1 , mm, 2) + R(jj - 1, mm, 1)) ; 
    end
         
    for jj = 2 : Nz - 1 
        S  = 0 ;

         for mm = Nx - 1 : -1 : ii  % Summation 
             S  = S + (R(jj + 1, mm, 2) + R(jj + 1, mm, 1)) - 2 * (R(jj, mm, 2) + R(jj, mm, 1)) + (R(jj - 1 , mm, 2) + R(jj - 1, mm, 1)) ; 
         end

        b(1)  =  2 *(R(1, ii, 1) + 2 * alpha * S1) ;       
        b(jj) =  2 *(R(jj, ii, 1) + alpha * S) ;
    end
end
toc

Elapsed time is 26.911663 seconds.
```

If computing time is a big concern, you can create some temporary variables before the `for` loop to avoid some summations/multiplications. This makes the code slightly worse to read, but it runs faster:

```
tic

Nz = 3636 ;  % Number of rows 
Nx = 910 ;   % Number of columns

R = rand(Nz, Nx, 2) ;
R12 = R(:,:,1)+R(:,:,2);
alpha = 3 ;

Nx1 = Nx-1;
Nz1 = Nz-1;
two_alpha = 2*alpha;

for ii = Nx1:-1:2                
    b = zeros(Nz, 1) ;

    S1 = 0 ;
    for mm = ii:Nx1 % Summation 
        S1 = S1 + R12(2, mm) - R12(1, mm) ; 
    end
    
    for jj = 2:Nz1
        S  = 0 ;
        for mm = ii:Nx1  % Summation 
            S  = S + R12(jj + 1, mm) -2*R12(jj, mm) + R12(jj - 1 , mm) ; 
        end
        b(1)  =  2 *(R(1, ii,1) + two_alpha*S1) ;       
        b(jj) =  2 *(R(jj, ii,1) + alpha*S) ;
    end
end
toc

Elapsed time is 12.202103 seconds.
```

Since the limits of summation extend up to N-1, creation of the `Nx1` and `Nz1` variables avoids three subtractions on each ii-loop. The `two_alpha` variable also avoids one multiplication per iteration. Creation of the `R12` also speeds up calculation, since in the original code this sum on the 3rd dimesion appears on every line of the summations.

I tried to also create a `two_R12=2*R12` variable for the `mm`-loop, but it runs slower since the for loop must access elements on two different variables.

You also stated that the `b` variable is used to solve a liner system `q = D\b`. This will also slow down computations. If the `D` matrix is constant, consider [decompose it](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/decomposition.html), in order to also speed up calculations.